# Angular 6 app routing does not work properly after deployment in iis 8.5

Tags: angular, iis

I have a website running on iis 8.5 .Every thing works fine in development time but after deployment on iis can't route manually writing path in url ,i mean when i write a path on url it always redirect to default route or even when i load page or  refresh page pressing F5 it redirect to default route. Otherwise Every thing work fine like when i click menu options its route correctly to the destination.

Example Default route, 192.10.10/Ecommerce/front       [it is default route]

when i am  trying to route manually  to  192.10.10/Ecommerce/admin

it is always redirecting  to default route. It happens for every manual route.

I use all angular deployment rule like URL Rewrite Module.

Comment: can you show your angular router? or some code atleast?

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ApplicationComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'front', pathMatch: "full" },
            { path: 'front', loadChildren: './frontend/frontend.module#FrontendModule' },
            { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/application/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@h.alhaj/angular-route-with-iis-shared-host-d8dfc80877c4